# Открытые методы в vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

В документации пишет,что метод не требует прав доступа,а по сути возвращает ошибку 5 (Авторизация пользователя не удалась. )
Метод этот
https://vk.com/dev/groups.get 
Вот пример моего запроса

```
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?user_id=1&extended=1&offset=5&count=2&v=5.44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот метод не требует от приложения каких-либо специальных [прав доступа](https://vk.com/dev/permissions). Однако он требует обязательной [авторизации](https://vk.com/dev/authentication)(параметр `access_token` в запросах).

Да, некоторые методы не требуют и авторизации(например [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get)), однако [groups.get](https://vk.com/dev/groups.get) к ним не относится.